# Writing to multiple files with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelly crawl webpage using multiprocessing pool and write the results into separate files.

As `Pool.apply` blocks until the function is completed, which makes the crawling perform like sequential behavior, so I changed it to `Pool.apply_async` and expect to process different districts parallelly.

```py
class crawl_job(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.website_url = 'https://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BR12AWRentalEnquiry/BR12PSearch.jsp'
        self.url ='https://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BR12AWRentalEnquiry/BR12SSearch?function=searchMarketRental'
        self.town_list = ["AMK","BD","BH","BB","BM","BP","BT","CT","CCK","CL","GL","HG","JE","JW","KWN","MP","PRC","PG","QT","SB","SK","SGN","TAP","TG","TP","WL","YS"]
        self.result_url = 'https://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BR12AWRentalEnquiry/BR12PResult.jsp'

        self.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36'}
        self.data = {
            'rbnSearchType': '1',
            'selTown': "AMK",
            'txtBlkFrm': '100',
            'txtBlkTo': '110',
            'dteMthFrm1': "Jun+2018",
            'dteMthTo1': "May+2019",
            'txtAmtFrm1':'',
            'txtAmtTo1':'',
            'txtBoundary':'',
            'txtBlk':'',
            'dteMthFrm2':'',
            'dteMthTo2':'',
            'txtAmtFrm2':'',
            'txtAmtTo2':'',
            'hdTempRentalEnq':''
            }
        self.params = {
            'function':'searchMarketRental'
        }
        self.s = requests.Session()
        self.s.headers.update(self.headers)
        self.s.get(self.website_url)
        self.result = []

    def crawl(self, town):
        result = []
        cur_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
        filename = f"{town}_{cur_date}.csv"
        for i in range(0, 1010, 10):
            block_range = (i, i+9)

            self.data.update({'selTown':town,
                        'txtBlkFrm': block_range[0],
                        'txtBlkTo': block_range[1],
                        'dteMthFrm1': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=2), '%b %Y'),
                        'dteMthTo1': datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%b %Y')})
            content = self.s.post(self.url, data=self.data, timeout=20, allow_redirects=False)
            if content.status_code == 302:
                if self.result_url == content.headers.get('location'):
                    output = self.s.get(content.headers.get('location'))
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(output.text, 'html.parser')
                    try:
                        table = soup.find('div',{'id':'result-non-paginated'})
                        table_body = table.find('tbody')
                        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
                        for row in rows:
                            cols = row.find_all('td')
                            cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
                            result.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
                    except AttributeError as e:
                        pass
                    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                        with open('log.txt','a') as f:
                            f.write('{} Error when crawling {}: {}\n'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), town, block_range))

        return (path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'hdb_rental', filename), result)
        # self.write_to_csv(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'hdb_rental', filename), result)

    def write_to_csv(self, x):
        filename, result = x
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    job = crawl_job()
    p_list = []
    pool = Pool(5)
    for town in job.town_list:
        pool.apply_async(job.crawl, (town, ), callback = job.write_to_csv)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

For each file it should contain different results for this district only, but I see the results are mixed up. 
One output file below, `AMK` for instance:

```sh
Jun 2019,Ang Mo Kio,235,Ang Mo Kio Avenue 3,4-Rm,2100.00
Jul 2019,Bukit Batok,241,Bukit Batok East Avenue 5,3-Rm,1500.00
Jul 2019,Bedok,182,Bedok North Road,4-Rm,2000.00
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I don't understand what you're asking.  This code gives the expected results?  Looking at it, it seems like it would do the right thing. 
 So then what are we supposed to be commenting on that doesn't behave correctly?  Are you asking us to guess about why code you aren't showing us might be misbehaving?  There are a bunch of smart people lurking here, but we're not clairvoyant.  Why don't you post your real code and ask about that?

Comment: Every CSV file contains its own results (<num>, <district_letter> for each row). I dont understand how it's mixed up. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Steve Thank you for the suggestions. I added the code for reference(previously I thought dump the whole code is not preferred here so I followed the structure to write sample snippets, sorry about that.)

Comment: @abdusco sorry I didn't make it clear. Added the original code I wrote, it seems results with district are not bound together because of multiprocessing, this is the problem I encountered.

Comment: I don't see you checking if the items you put in `result` actually match `town`

Comment: Hi @JanneKarila `town` is updated in `data` for each post request, so the returned result should match `town`

Comment: There may be a difference between what the server actually returns and what you expect it to return. Better check what the response really contains.

Comment: Identified the problem is due to class object, need to initialise the instance for each town.